# Unknown function format in JS es2015

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

First time in my life I see this function and can't understand how it's works

`export default foobar(val1)(val2);`

I haven't got the full code, just this little line of it and I understand what's  `export default` but what the second `(val2)` mean? How it's work?

Comment: `foobar` is a function like `foobar = a => b => c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foobar is a function that returns a function.

In ES5 it would look something like this:

```
foobar(){
  return function(){...};
}
```

An example:

```
function saySomething(thing){
  return function(otherThing){
   console.log(thing + otherThing);
  }
}

//say hello bob
var sayHello = saySomething('hello ');
sayHello('bob');
```

I can achieve the samething without creating an
intermediate variable to store sayHello:

```
saySomething('hello ')('bob');
```

This allows you to exploit closures to compose new functions.

Answer (score 1):

foo is returning a function

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/susasupabo/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var foo = function (val1) {
  console.log(val1);
  return function (val2) {
    console.log(val2);
  };
};

foo('abc')('xyz');
```

Output:
'abc'
'xyz'